# Bouncy Castle for iOS (Objective C)

Tags: ios, bouncycastle

Is there a version of Bouncy Castle that be used in the development of iOS applications ?

Any feedback would be highly appreciated. Googling did not answer the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bouncy Castle is for C# and Java only...

For Objective C you can use following though...

- [OpenSSL](http://openssl.org/) for cryptography
- [SSLCrypto](http://septicus.com/products/opensource/) for COCOA

You can visit http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/CCCryptor.3cc.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/3cc/CCCryptor for more details as there are in-build functions to do this...

Comment: I would like to know is there any library come for bouncy castle in objc or swift??

Answer (score 4):

Nope, 90% of the time the encryption goes through Apple's own CommonCrypto library. Luckily, there are a few very easy to use wrappers for the CommonCrypto, check out [RNCryptor](https://github.com/rnapier/RNCryptor) by Rob Napier.